# mySql query with HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT) with AND and OR (inclusive and exclusive clause)

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, having-clause

I have to modify a mySql custom query inside a Wordpress site.
I will try to explain you my issue, simplifing the query to that is really needed to know.

The table *cms_posts* (alias 'p') is INNER JOINED to the  *cms_term_relationship* table (alias 'term_rel').
I neet to find all *cms_posts* with a *term_rel.term_taxonomy* value included IN 211,210,10,9.
My current query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    p.id
FROM cms_posts p 
    INNER JOIN cms_term_relationships term_rel 
        ON term_rel.object_id = p.id 
WHERE
    term_rel.term_taxonomy_id IN (211,210,10,9)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING  
    COUNT(DISTINCT term_rel.term_taxonomy_id) = 4
LIMIT 0, 50
```

The **COUNT(DISTINCT** ensures that all the relationships i ask in the WHERE clause are striclty followed.

It all works flawless.

But i need to modify the query!
I need to split the WHERE clause. I try to make an example.

I need to take all posts with term_taxonomy in 211 **AND** 210 but also in 10 **OR** 9.
I search for all these combinations of posts:
211, 210, 10
211, 210, 9
So i need that 211 and 210 **are both needed**, but only 1 occurrence of 10 **OR** 9 are needed too.

Verbosely, i need that my posts are in X, Y, Z categories and at least in A, B or C categories. X, Y, Z categories are exlusive; A, B, C are inclusive.

The question is not so easy to be explained, and my horrible english don't help.
I hope that someone understand my english and even my issue :D

Comment: you need to provide schema of these table as all on SO may dont know how wordpress works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mureinik for the answer, but if i try to implement your code, using a case expression it seems doesn't work. If i well understand your aim, with that CASE all the 'inclusive terms', but the first one, are not been considered by the COUNT(DISTINCT. I probably did not implement in the right way your code, but the results was not good enough.

**But perhaps i have a solution.**
Let me try to give you a better explaination:
- *exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id* is the field to search into;
- there is a list of **exclusive values** for *exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id*
- and there is also a list of **inclusive values** for *exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id*

If the user make a search for 211, 210, 9, 217, 215, 218, 10 values of *exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id*, what i need to do first is to separate the exclusive from the inclusive ones.

I obtain 2 lists:
- exclusives 211, 210
- inclusives 9, 217, 215, 218, 10

After that i can compose this query, with **2 JOINS** on the same field but calling the resulting field with 2 different aliases, and then makeing a COUNT(DISTINCT only on the exclusive terms.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.id,
FROM cms_posts p
    INNER JOIN cms_term_relationships exclusive_terms ON exclusive_terms.object_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN cms_term_relationships inclusive_terms ON inclusive_terms.object_id = p.id
WHERE 
    exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id IN (211, 210) 
    AND
    inclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id IN (9, 217, 215, 218, 10)
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT exclusive_terms.term_taxonomy_id) = 2
LIMIT 0, 50
```

It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

A `having` clause with `count distinct` is still a valid approach. What you could do, for example, is use a case expression to treat IDs 9 and 10 the same, thus allowing you to continue counting the distinct number IDs you need. E.g.:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    p.id
FROM vf_posts p 
    INNER JOIN vf_term_relationships term_rel 
        ON term_rel.object_id = p.id 
WHERE
    term_rel.term_taxonomy_id IN (211,210,10,9)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING  
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE term_rel.term_taxonomy_id 
                        WHEN 9 THEN 10 
                        ELSE term_rel.term_taxonomy_id
                   END) = 4 -- Here!
LIMIT 0, 50
```